# QT + winapi (MessageBox)

Tags: qt, winapi

Мне в Qt необходимо вызвать winapi функцию MessageBoxA, делаю это так

```
void Show_Message()
{
     QLibrary qLib;
     char win_NameWin[] = "Test", win_MessageWin[] = "Test";
     int iResult = 0x00;
     bool unLoad = false;

     qLib.setFileName("user32");

     if(qLib.load())
     {
          if(qLib.isLoaded())
          {
             typedef int (*pMessageBox)(void* hWnd, char *lpText, char *lpCaption, unsigned int uType);

             pMessageBox MessageBoxA = (pMessageBox)qLib.resolve("MessageBoxA");

             if(MessageBoxA)
             {
                 iResult = MessageBoxA(nullptr, &win_NameWin[0x00], &win_MessageWin[0x00], 0x40);
             }

             MessageBoxA = nullptr;

             unLoad = qLib.unload();
         }
    }
}
```

MessageBox выводиться, но при выходе из функции Show_Message() выскакивает исключение и программа аварийно закрывается...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

qLib.unload() возвращает false - не пойму в чем проблема...

PS У меня приложение без окна, работает в фоновом режиме и при старте, мне необходима некая информация. Ничего лучше, я не придумал, как вывести её на экран в виде MessageBox т. к. стандартный QMessageBox не работает.

Comment: А какой тип приложения у вас? QCoreApplication?
Почему вы не линкуете user32 статически?

Comment: Зачем загружать user32 и импортировать функцию вручную? Если уж делаете так, то используйте хотя бы правильную сигнатуру из SDK.